# How do I add a new Project including some .cs files to my solution from a .NET 6.0 application?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm working on a code generator. After the code is generated, a new Class Library project should be added to my solution which includes the generated files.

What's the best way of doing that?

Comment: AFAIK, you don't. Code generators are supposed to generate files in the project they are added to. You *could* have an empty class library with code generators though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Microsoft.Build](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild) library (and related nuget [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/17.5.0?_src=template)). I've used it in the pasts for .NET framework projects and previous versions of VS projects.

This is a sample of the code to add a code file:

```
var type = "Compile";
var project = new Project(projectFileLocation);
project.AddItem(type, filePath);
project.Save();
```

The `Project` object is defined in `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation`.